# Issues Booting Ubuntu from USB Drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 from my USB, but the computer boots too quickly to select a boot option. Any suggests?

Comment: Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Please ask this question in Ask Ubuntu community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may sound a lil bit stupid but,
I usually just smash f2 like crazy while its booting so I can get to the BIOS menu and then choose de booting device from there, would not that work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try holding F2 while starting up your PC, even before pressing the power button.